# Is it possible to delete chat with type "DIRECT_MESSAGE" using Google Chat API?

Tags: c#, .net, google-chat

I'm trying to delete "DIRECT_MESSAGE" chat using Google Chat API and .Net library Google.Apis.HangoutsChat.v1 :

`await service.Spaces.Delete(spaceName).ExecuteAsync();`

As a result, I get an error : "Google.GoogleApiException: 'The service chat has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is BadRequest. Invalid space type: DIRECT_MESSAGE. Specify a space type of SPACE.  Can I delete chats with this type?

I tried to modify the chat from DIRECT_MESSAGE to SPACE before deleting it, but then I also got an error. As a result, I was expecting a direct conversation to be deleted